# What font is used in this picture:

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-face

I was just wondering if anyone could place a font for me? I need it for a font-face on a website.

[image: Site screenshot]

What font is used for "Good food compliments great beer" text?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would help if it were a bit bigger. It's probably Georgia (with reduced tracking) since their current site still uses that in a few places. It probably not Baskerville because the centre point of *M* doesn't meet the baseline and the tail of the lowercase *d* is straight not curved.

Comment: I'd vote up if I could but I'm to new, lol. George is a lot closer than I thought on first inspection Andrew. I might see if any other suggestions come in before I hit the tick :)

Comment: No, it was Georgia. Tick to you sir. Thanks very much.

Comment: I was also thinking of Baskerville, but although "g" seemed to have disjoint counter it didn't have high enough ear and "f" wasn't wide enough. So I though of tightly tracked Georgia as well. +1